# How do you remove file named: "str\\escape.rs"

Tags: unix, rm

It's weird that I could not "rm -rf str\\escape.rs"
And even if I just simply put "rm -rf *.rs" nothing changes
The file is just there..

This file is from source of cm10.2 as well as cm12. But this is just weird.. any thoughts would be appreciated!

**Update:**
So if I do:

```
rm 'str\\escape.rs'
```

It throws error that

```
rm: cannot remove `str\\\\escape.rs': No such file or directory
```

**Update2:**
The permission is

```
-rwxrwx--- 0 myu myu 53 May 21 00:17 str\\escape.rs
```

And I tried few things like type "rm " and then press tab (since it's the only file left..), it gives

```
rm str\\\\escape.rs
```

and something like removing the directory that contains this file "rm -rf P_str_escape". It either says

```
rm: cannot remove `str\\\\escape.rs': No such file or directory
```

or

```
rm: cannot remove `P_str_escape': Directory not empty
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape more slashes:

```
rm -rf str\\\\escape.rs
```

Edit: I just tried this, and it works fine:

```
$ ls
str\\escape.rs
$ rm str\\\\escape.rs
$ ls
$
```

Comment: @user2638327 You must be doing something wrong. I just tried this and it works fine.

Comment: If I type "rm " and press tab, it gives "rm str\\\\escape.rs" and then press Enter, it says "rm: cannot remove `str\\\\escape.rs': No such file or directory". Do you think there are other possibilities this could go wrong?

Comment: hm. now it looks like file system problems, not just name escaping. What FS is on the partion where this files stored? And just several more steps to check:  did you try to remove it with help of any filemanager, e.g. MidnightCommander? You showed file permissions, but what is your user (you can show output of "id" command)?

Comment: @user2638327, try to check your filesystem for errors (with fsck, if it's linux partition)

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two options:

- take file name in single quotes, to avoid bash substitutions:

  ```
  rm 'str\\escape.rs'
  ```

  Evidence:

  ```
  $ touch 'str\\escape.rs'
  $ ls  'str\\escape.rs'
  str\\escape.rs
  $ rm 'str\\escape.rs'
  $ ls  'str\\escape.rs'
  str\\escape.rs: No such file or directory
  ```
- Just escape slashes:

  ```
  rm str\\\\escape.rs
  ```

More information about how escaping works:
http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/escapingsection.html

Comment: When I do: rm 'str\\escape.rs', it says: rm: cannot remove `str\\\\escape.rs': No such file or directory

Comment: what shell and OS do you use? I added example how it works for me in bash and linux

Comment: thanks for replying.. I am on Ubuntu 12.04. When I do 'rm str\\\\escape.rs' as you suggest, it still throws "rm: cannot remove `str\\\\escape.rs': No such file or directory"